# Error DEP0100 deploying from VS to PI3 with Win10 IoT

Tags: windows, visual-studio, uwp, raspberry-pi, iot

I hope you can help me out on this one.

I'm currently developing an UWP app with VS 2017 which is supposed to run on a Raspberry Pi
3 running Win10 IoT. I've successfully deployed it to the Raspberry about two weeks ago and
haven't developed on it since.

Now I wanted to deploy the app onto the Raspberry again, but it doesn't work
anymore. Everytime I get the error:

**Error DEP0100 : Please ensure that target device has developer mode enabled.
Could not obtain a developer license due to error 80004001.**

Things I have tried and checked:

- My Win10 machine is still in developer mode. I've tried switching it on and
  off.
- I restarted VS and the Pi multiple times
- I tried to deploy it in Release and Debug mode
- I cleaned and rebuilt the solution multiple times
- I tried changing authentication to "none"
- I tried changing the minimum/target version of the project
- updated all NuGet packages
- checked if I'm signed into VS

Been wasting way too many hours on this and I'm really hoping for a solution!

Comment: Which build of Windows IoT Core are you using on the device? Have you tried to install/reinstall the Windows IoT Core?Which build of Visual Studio 2017 are you developing with? You can try to update the Visual Studio to the latest build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by re-flashing Windows 10 IoT onto the SD card and starting from scratch.